# How to queue CSS3 animations when shown after page scroll (JSFiddle provided)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/mh7e8/1/**

I have 3 images I want to add a `.animation` class to so that they reveal with a bounce:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 steps">
  <img src="./s3/img/sprite-circle-1.png" class="step-1 bounceIn">
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4 steps">
  <img src="./s3/img/sprite-circle-2.png" class="step-2 bounceIn">
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4 steps">
  <img src="./s3/img/sprite-circle-3.png" class="step-3 bounceIn">
  </div>
</div>
```

I already have a very nice (working) CSS3 animation:

```
.animated.bounceIn{
// code: see JSFIDDLE - http://jsfiddle.net/mh7e8/1/ for detail
}
```

I want the class to apply to each image, with a 1 second delay between them, when the first image loads on the screen.

I have the code to determine when the element is visible (working):

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.isVisible = function (partial, hidden, direction) {

 // working code: see JSFIDDLE - http://jsfiddle.net/mh7e8/1/ for detail


})(jQuery);
$(function () {

    var $bounceIn = $('.step-1');
    var testVis = function () {
        $bounceIn.each(function () {
            if ($(this).isVisible()) {
                console.log("step-1 visible");
            }

});
};

$(window).on('scroll resize', testVis);
testVis();
});
```

Where I am struggling is to find how to delay each animation sequentially. Applying a delay to the CSS transition doesn't seem to invoke consistent behaviour accross browsers (e.g. step-2 can load before step 1). How can I queue this in jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the CSS animations and attach them to specific classes.

#### CSS

```
.slideUp {
  animation: slide-up 1500ms ease;
}
```

#### JQUERY

```
/* these are the classes you want to animate */
toAnimate = ['step1', 'step2', 'step3']

/* iterate over this array and apply the *slideup* class */
$.each(toAnimate, function(i, class) {
  window.timeout(function {
    $('.parent').find(class).addClass('slideUp')
  }, i*1000);
}
```

Now, just use jQuery to add those classes to the elements at the appropriate times (for example, with a delay of 1 second, add the `.slideUp` class to the four images, etc)

Comment: In order to have incremental delays for each image, @alias51 could set the animation-delay property individually through `.css()` before adding the `.animate` class.

Comment: @kumar Yes... that would be the essence of the question! How do I do this? :)

Comment: @janfoeh Unfortunately with separate elements and a scroll, not all browsers will queue delays in the right order, so this doesn't work.

Comment: @alias51 good to know. Any browser in particular you noticed a problem with?

Comment: something from the top of my head... there may be some issues (semicolons etc), just let me know if it works or not...

Comment: @janfoeh All of the big 3 have issues. E.g. Chrome, if you have 3 separate elements aligns on the same horizontal position and scroll slowly, then the delay works. Scroll fast, and step-2 or step-3 randomly fire first.

Comment: @alias51: with jquery's `.each()` the elements will be fetched in order of appearance in DOM, so the class will apply in order, and everything should be smooth

Comment: @KumarHarsh Thanks, I'm not clear how I create 3 sequential steps for each image using this, based on when `.step-1` is first visible?